# Retriving data from an express.js route with Angular

Tags: angular

So I'm trying to call a link from my Angular service with http, but I can't retrieve the data. Would appreciate any help!

Here's the code:

Express file:

```
router.get("/tickets/ticketList", function(req,res){

user.ticketList(function(result){
    return result; //This is the data from the db

})
});
```

Service typescript file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  x(){
    return this.http.get("localhost:2000/tickets/ticketList");


  }

  }
```

And the component file where I the use the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{ UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-event',
  templateUrl: './add-event.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-event.component.css']
})
export class AddEventComponent implements OnInit {
 private userlist:any;
  constructor(private test:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit():void{
    this.test.x().subscribe((userlist) =>{
      this.userlist = userlist;
    })
  }


}
```

This is really confusing to me, and I'd really really appreciate any help in solving this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Did you set your CORS headers?**

If you are running your client and server code on seperate domans, you need to add CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) headers. These are headers that allow your webpage to be accessed from seperate domains.

**For example, if your using localhost:3000 for your server and localhost:4200 for your client.**

If this is the issue, sticking this express middleware into your node.js code should work:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
```